# Not all empty cells are formatted to text xlsx angular

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx, sheetjs

I generate a new excel spreadsheet using the following code.  The first row shows the column names and the rest of the spreadsheet will have empty cells.  I am trying to set the format of the empty cells to Text, using the following code.  But it only sets the format to text for the first row below the column header row.  Is there way to set all empty cells to Text format.

```
    let columnFormatArray = new Array(columnNames.length);
    columnFormatArray.fill({ v: '', t: 's', z: '@' });

        const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([columnNames, columnFormatArray]);
         XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet);
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'Testing.xlsx', { sheetStubs: true})
```